# SSH error on the clone Virtual Machine

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I have one VM machine on the staging server then I import it to my local Virtualbox and I got the error when I try to ssh to the Virtual Machine on my local computer.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you SSH to a host, the host public key is stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

Your system is warning you that the key for the host at 192.168.1.148 has changed. This could be an indicator of a man-in-the-middle attack.

In your case, this is most probably because the same IP address (192.168.1.148) was allocated at some point to a different VM (with a different public key) and that you accessed that VM through SSH.

To fix this, simply delete the offending key (at line 40) from ~/.ssh/known_hosts. You can do this with:

`sed -i '40d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`